Convergence in $L^1$, implies converges in $L^1$ for the corresponding binarized succession?
Let $X_n$ a succession of random variables with $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: \mathbb{P}(X_n=x)>0\} \subseteq[0,1]$ $\forall n$, and X a random variable with $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: \mathbb{P}(X=x)>0\} \subseteq[0,1]$ too.
If $\mathbb{E}[|X_n-X|]\rightarrow 0$, is it true that $\mathbb{E}[|\mathbb{1}_{[k,1]}(X_n)-\mathbb{1}_{[k,1]}(X)|]\rightarrow 0$?
Where $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{1}_{[k,1]}(\cdot)$ is the indicator function, equal to 1 if the argument is in $[0,1]$, 0 otherwise.
[UPDATE] Generally, no (see @user6247850 counterexample). What if I further assume continuos CDF or add any similar assumption? I am ultimately interested in showing this result (which I have already observed via Monte Carlo simulations).

No, this is not always the case.  Consider $X$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X=k) > 0$ and define $X_n := X-\frac 1n$.  Then $\mathbb{E}[|X_n-X|] = \frac 1n \rightarrow 0$, but $\mathbb{E}[|1_{[k,1]}(X_n)-1_{[k,1]}(X)|] \ge \mathbb{P}(X = k) \not \rightarrow 0$.

True. Is there any additional simple assumption I can add to still obtain this result?
For example, continuous CDF?

Yes, if $X$ has a continuous CDF then this would follow from the fact that $L^1$ convergence implies convergence in distribution and the portmanteau theorem.

Why do you need continuous CDF for Portmanteau theorem?

@RiccardoCadei To rule out examples like the one I provided.

May I kindly ask you for a reference for a clear formulation of Portmanteau theorem stating this hypothesis?

@RiccardoCadei It's standard practice on this site to accept answers if they address the statement of your question and ask follow ups as separate questions.  Regardless, continuity of the CDF of $X$ is to make $[k,1]$ a continuity set for all $k$.

To match the support condition, I think you want something like $X_n = \max(X - \frac1n, 0)$.

I still don't understand how we use the Portmanteau theorem in this proof.
